# Raspberry pi Touchscreen CSI to HDMI extension

Tags: pi-4, hdmi, touchscreen

I need to connect my raspberry pi 7 inch touchscreen to my raspberry pi board from a distance of 5m, so I bought some CSI/HDMI extensions that seem to work great with a 1m cable, but when I try o connect a 5m one the screen stays white which means that the board recognizes the touchscreen but can't communicate the data to make the display work so my signal is getting lost due to the distance.

I've been thinking abut a solution for this and thought about purchasing one HDMI repeater but not sure if it would work since this is CSI serial communication, also thought that maybe if I get a really high quality HDMI cable it might work.

what do you think of those ideas and if you got any better ones please fell free to post down below.

Comment: Forgive me but I thought the CSI port was camera only...

Comment: yes I guess for touchscreen its called DSI, but the same adaptors work for both just cant get it working with 5m hdmi cable but touch screen works great with 1m HDMI cable

Answer (score 0):

DSI is intended for short discances only. Talking about centimeters here.
There are no mitigations for interferences in place as in HDMI.
But also with HDMI depending on the cable Quality, the outupt signal strength (which you can adjust in /boot/config.txt - btw) and the resolution (required bandwidth), you can only hope to get more than 2m reliably.

Comment: The crazy thing is that I have my camera also at 5m using the same adapters and same HDMI cable and I have no issues

Comment: So you are bridging the CSI/DSI Interface with an adapter to HDMI and back to CSI/DSI. Cameras don’t use the same bandwidth. A camera does not provide uncompressed 1080p @60Hz but has at least YUV reduced color space resolution. Also the Signal voltage (Not sure if it is the case here) makes a difference.

Comment: Have a look at https://www.adafruit.com/product/3671 they reckon they where lucky to get 2m compared to 25cm!

Answer (score 0):

also had related issues with a cheap hdmi-switch.

soution for me was this small and cheap HDMI to HDMI signal-conditioner/refresher:

Speaka HM-CV045K